# Losing session attributes in a particular JSP

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, struts

I'm working on a Struts 1 application. I'm setting some session attributes in the Action class. There is a JSP file, the link is below. When a form gets submitted from this jsp, or a another action method invoked from this JSP, intermittently the session attributes which I set previously are missing. But those two are getting lost at the same time. I have put the logs in the action class which this jsp get submitted to to check the session attributes. I get null for that sometimes.

The session attributes that I set in the action class are,

```
session.setAttribute("memberExlan", new Boolean(memberExlan)); and 
request.getSession().setAttribute("userId","useridfromthedatabase");
```

file link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7cP7V7_i1LdWnRwT2FpSmR1akE/edit?usp=sharing

Please help.

Comment: You can check session attributes in jsp

Comment: In jsp, it is always there, but when submitting to the action class only it gets lost.

Comment: you can send session id to the action and get the session from the context, then get back your attributes

Comment: If you're setting them properly they'll still be there. Check for HTTP vs. HTTPS, some app servers use different sessions by default, but are configurable to share. If it's intermittent then I'd look for session replication-based timing issues if you're in a clustered environment. Without further information it's impossible to help; it's very unlikely there's an issue with session management itself if you're able to retrieve values intermittently--it's more likely there's a development, conceptual, or server-based issue.

Comment: Thank you @DaveNewton. It is http vs https error. the jsp page goes as https. but with submit it comes as http. 
The action url I set is like this,
var url="../reservation/ResSearchCriteria.do?
This calls http. How can I change it use https. Should I use the full url starting var = "https://..."
Thank you.